# How to make the layouts in a viewflipper random

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to display layouts randomly in a view flipper (I have 4 layouts - they will be many more). This is what I have so far

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Random mRandom = new Random();



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ViewFlipper simpleViewFlipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.simpleViewFlipper);

    Animation in = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, android.R.anim.fade_in);
    Animation out = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, android.R.anim.fade_out);

    simpleViewFlipper.setInAnimation(in);
    simpleViewFlipper.setOutAnimation(out);

    simpleViewFlipper.setFlipInterval(3000);
    simpleViewFlipper.setAutoStart(true);

    simpleViewFlipper.setDisplayedChild(mRandom.nextInt(4));

}
```

}

I want them to randomly show and never stop.

Please bare in mind that I'm a beginner :)

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You might want to read about [asking good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as this one is too broad to answer and only shows limited research effort.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you getting your images from? Are the images in your DB or only in SRC folder? Any attemps on the coding? Give us a little more information.

For example...

```
setContentView(R.layout.yourxml);
     ArrayList<uploadsclass> currentuploads = new ArrayList<uploadsclass>();
            currentuploads.add(new uploadsclass("MYBRAND NEW AUDI", "1.6TDI, 220 CCM, diesel", R.drawable.audi));
```

uploadsclassadapter addtoList = new uploadsclassadapter(this, currentuploads);

```
    // Get a reference to the ListView, and attach the adapter to the listView.
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview_ids);
    listView.setAdapter(addtoList);
```

yourxml.xml:

```
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/listview_ids"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" />
```

your listitems.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/oneCarImage"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.04" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/quickInfo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/quickCharacteristics"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```